# How to show ViewPager in NestedScrollView in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, nestedscrollview

Please help me, my ViewPager is not visible in NestedScrollView. What should i do? I have spent much time to try to make vp visible but it's not success. If i set fixed height of viewpager then it will be visible, but i don't want that. Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.StoryDetailActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/test"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_6x"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_1x">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_1x">

                <com.nm.story.widgets.textview.TextViewLight
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_views"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xnormal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/tiny_icon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tiny_icon"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_grey" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/divider"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:background="@color/dividerColor" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_1x">

                <com.nm.story.widgets.textview.TextViewLight
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_likes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xnormal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/tiny_icon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tiny_icon"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_like_grey" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/divider"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:background="@color/dividerColor" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_1x"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_1x">

                <com.nm.story.widgets.textview.TextViewLight
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_chapter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xnormal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/divider"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2x"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2x"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor" />

        <com.nm.story.widgets.textview.TextViewItalic
            android:id="@+id/lbl_review"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_2x"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xnormal" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_chapter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2x"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2x" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_chapter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2x"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2x"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add in </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Comment: and go through https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-viewpager-nestedscrollview-bukhori-aqid

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a question, if i set ViewPager as the direct child of Coordinator, where should i put lbl_review and tabs_chapter?